# Hide link after iframe is loaded

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, hyperlink, load

I have this code to hide iframe until link is clicked

```
<a href="http://www.site.com/" target="iframe1" onClick="document.getElementById('iframe1').parentNode.style.display=''">link</a>

</br></br>

<div style="display:none;"><iframe id="iframe1" name="iframe1" src="#"></iframe></div>
```

I want to hide link after iframe is loaded

How i can do that please ?

If there is code is better than my code please post it too

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Change your link to this:

```
<a href="http://www.site.com/" target="iframe1" onClick="document.getElementById('iframe1').parentNode.style.display='block'; this.style.display = 'none';">link</a>
```

It sets the style of the link to `display: none`.

Also, I set the display for the iframe to block instead of ''. You should consider moving your css and javascript outside of your HTML into external files, or at least to a `<style>` tag for CSS and a `<script>` tag for JS.

Comment: Please, if i want to move javascript outside HTML..what is should do to let js connect with <a> ?

Comment: You would assign the <a> tag an id, and then use document.getElementById to retrieve it, and then set its onclick function to use the function that you currently have set as onClick in your tag.

Comment: I'm sorry..i'm so bad with JS..i have tried many of times..could do it for me pleaseee

Answer (score 1):

Use jQuery's .load() event:

> The load event is sent to an element when it and all sub-elements have been completely loaded. This event can be sent to any element associated with a URL: images, scripts, frames, **iframes**, and the window object.

```
  $("#iframe").load(function(){
      $("#link").hide();
   });
```

Comment: Thank you i'm trying to use it..could you write a full code for how it should exactly be with my code please ?